# Increment "i" inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a presentation made with vanilla javascript. And I have a for loop that creates sliders.
In this for loop I have to

```
for (var i = 0; i < prod_lorem.img; i++) {
    inhtml += "<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="img"><img src="assets/img/products/' + products_cat + '/' + prod_lorem.img + '/' + i + '.png" alt=""></div><div class="img"><img src="assets/img/products/' + products_cat + '/' + prod_lorem.img + '/' + i++ + '.png" alt=""></div></div>";
}
```

In second img class i++ and i+1 (this prints 01) didn't worked and I can't use two loops. I have to do this in one loop to not break the code.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are doing string concatenation inside a string literal? Makes no sense.

Comment: So why don't you just loop by 2 and add one in the output?

Comment: It is a duplicate of above question in c++ (the syntax is same).

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your alternation of double `"` and single `'` quotation marks. Furthermore you are using a template strings, where your variables should be enclosed within `${` and `}`, without concatenation

Comment: Please post the prod_lorem and products_cat

Comment: Thank you for your comments but answer from here solved it already. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `++i`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < prod_lorem.img; i++) {
    inhtml += '<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="img"><img src="assets/img/products/' + products_cat + '/' + prod_lorem.img + '/' + i + '.png" alt=""></div><div class="img"><img src="assets/img/products/' + products_cat + '/' + prod_lorem.img + '/' + ++i + '.png" alt=""></div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ` symbol is a template literal. You're joining your strings incorrectly.
You need to use ${} to do replacements.

Also, you don't want to increment i inside the loop, as it is used to control the loop.

```
    inhtml += `
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="assets/img/products/${products_cat}/${prod_lorem.img}/${i}.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="assets/img/products/${products_cat}/${prod_lorem.img}/${i + 1}.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>`;
```

Comment: Oh sorry totally forgot about it. Editing question now.

Comment: prod_lorem.img was a variable also

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

```js
const prod_lorem = { img : 5 }
const products_cat = "abc";
const html = Array.from({ length: prod_lorem.img }).map((_,i) => `
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="assets/img/products/${products_cat}/${i}/${i}.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="assets/img/products/${products_cat}/${i}/${i+1}.png" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>`).join("");



console.log(html)
```